# Network sniffing raw format with socket programming at python

Tags: python-3.x, networking, network-programming

I want to sniff network traffic. I used to this code

but this code sniff only TCP packets. I want to sniff all packet formats. How can i do this.

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_TCP)

while True:
    print s.recvfrom(65565)
```

etc. if i sniff UDP packets, i using to this code

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)

while True:
    print s.recvfrom(65565)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Scapy module for python. You can sniff all protocols with Scapy. If you want to see which protocol supported, type ls() to Scapy console.

for more details, please check this source: https://github.com/besimaltnok/scapy-cheatsheet

Best regards,
Besim.